# "Source not found" after alteration in code

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

i have written two sets of code following a book. It just displays a dialog with some checkboxes, functionality wise they are alike, but they differ slightly programmatically. The first runs fine in the emulator, the second says "source not found in JAR  android.jar

**Works:**

```
public class DialogActivity2 extends Activity {
   CharSequence[] items = { "Google", "Apple", "Microsoft" };
   boolean[] itemsChecked = new boolean [items.length];

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    showDialog(0); 
}

@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
    case 0:
        return new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
        .setTitle("This is a dialog with some simple text...")

        .setPositiveButton("OK",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                    "OK clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        )

        .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                    "Cancel clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        )

        .setMultiChoiceItems(items, itemsChecked,
            new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {                  
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int wich, boolean isChecked) {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), items[wich] + (isChecked ? " checked!" : " unchecked!"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                       
                }
            }
        ).create();         
    }
    return null;
}

 @Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
     getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
     return true;
 }
}
```

**Generates "Source not found":**

```
public class DialogActivity1 extends Activity { 
   CharSequence[] items = { "Goole", "Apple", "Microsoft" };
   boolean[] itemsChecked = new boolean[items.length];

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dialog_activity1);
}

public void onClick(View v) {           
    showDialog(0);
}

@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {       
    switch (id) {
    case 0:
        Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        builder.setTitle("Dialog with some text...");           
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {                 
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int wichButton) {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "OK clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        );

        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", 
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {                     
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Cancel clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            }
        );

        builder.setMultiChoiceItems(items, itemsChecked,
            new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int wich, boolean isChecked) {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                    items[wich] + (isChecked ? " checked" : " unchecked"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                          
                }
            }
        );
        return builder.create();
    }
    return null;
}

 @Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
 {
     // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
     getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_dialog_activity1, menu);
     return true;
 }

}
```

Comment: Can you post the entire error message?

Comment: Now I can't seem to duplicate the error message, or im not viewing the right output. A new tab just opens with the title: "ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, intent) line:1955. The text in this window says "Source not found" (in red text) and a button with "Edit Source Lookup Path..."

Comment: Is this output in the logcat window? If so, it might be the case that you've not declared this activity in your Manifest

Comment: It was in the debug window, when i clicked one of the threads. The logcat with error filter contains som 30 lines. http://pastebin.com/GLz3cf2T

I did check the manifest, and all seems to be in order. However, the graphical editor for the layout xml is all gray. It does not seem to be loading the xml. Im going to rewrite the entire project. Thank you for taking the time to help out!